# Using Google Maps or Bing Maps provided as WMS in MapInfo Professional?

Tags: google-maps, mapinfo, bing-maps

Is there any way that I could use google maps or bing map or other free map provider as WMS in MapInfo Professional 10.0?

Comment: If only this were true. There is no Bing option in WMS nor is Google there. Neither seem to have WMS access.

Comment: there is a product called mapper G its about $300 if that helps, im just looking into it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've been able to do this for ages.  In 10.5, you can add bing maps via a one click operation.

Options>Toolbars>Web Services

Quote from the user guide:

*Server-Side Authentication for WMS and WFS:
You can access WFS and WMS servers that require basic authentication using the built-in standard mechanism for internet servers. To connect to a WFS or WMS server that requires authentication, complete the Connect dialog box that displays.*

[10 user guide](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/10/MapInfoProfessionalUserGuide.pdf)

[Tips and tricks WMS](http://www.twiav.nl/files/TWIAV_TIP_MI002.pdf)